# LiveData is not updating the list in TabFragment when viewcreated

Tags: android-livedata, android-tabhost, android-viewpager2

I am just stuck here and tried a lot many things but didn't get the solution so the problem is

**I am having a Tab host and inside it two tab items and used viewpager2 for displaying the contents from the api using the live data**

```
private fun getAdslot() {
        rewardViewModel.aye.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){networkResult->
            if(networkResult.status == "success"){
                if(networkResult.offers.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "No Task Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }else{
                    adapter.taskGAmeList = networkResult
                    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    Log.d("TaskTabFragment", "getAdslot: $networkResult")
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

`Problem:`
so when the parent fragment is created the data is not displayed and also i am getting the list as 0

**but soon as I click on the Task again or move from task to reward tab and then to task tab the data list is fetched from the api and the contents are displayed**

[image]

here is the code for the adapter

```
class TabItemTaskAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<TabItemTaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder>() {

    var taskGAmeList:AyetAdSlot?=null


    inner class TaskViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
//        val gameImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_game)
        val gameName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_game_name)
        val gameSubtitle:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_game_subtitle)
        val rewardPrize:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reward_amount)
        val ivGameIcon: AppCompatImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_game_icon)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_task_reward_layout,parent,false)
        return TaskViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("TabItemTaskAdapter", "getItemCount: ${taskGAmeList!!.offers.size}")
        return taskGAmeList!!.offers.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("RewardTabFragment", "onBindViewHolder: ${taskGAmeList!!.offers.size}")
        val currentItem = taskGAmeList!!.offers[position]
        holder.gameName.text = currentItem.name
        holder.gameSubtitle.text = currentItem.description
        holder.rewardPrize.text = currentItem.currency_amount.toString()
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(currentItem?.icon).override(96).
        into(holder.ivGameIcon)
    }

}
```

below is the code where i am using the tablayout

```
private fun setUpTaskRewardTabLayout(){
        binding.tabLayoutTaskReward.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.light_grey),ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.primary_text_color))
        taskRewardTabLayoutAdapter = TaskRewardTabLayoutAdapter(childFragmentManager,lifecycle)
        binding.viewPager.adapter = taskRewardTabLayoutAdapter

        Log.d("RewardTabFragment", "setUpTaskRewardTabLayout: ${binding.tabLayoutTaskReward.selectedTabPosition} ")
        binding.tabLayoutTaskReward.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                Log.d("RewardTabFragment", "onTabSelected: ${tab!!.position} ")
                binding.viewPager.currentItem = tab.position

                taskRewardTabLayoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                taskRewardTabLayoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

                taskRewardTabLayoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        })


        //for Swiping the tab
        binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                binding.tabLayoutTaskReward.selectTab(binding.tabLayoutTaskReward.getTabAt(position))
                taskRewardTabLayoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })
    }
```

// FragmentstateAdapter for setting the fragments

```
class TaskRewardTabLayoutAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return if(position==0){
            TaskTabFragment()
        } else{
            RewardTabFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

**Can anyone help me out this**

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a solution but found a Makeshifter (Jugaad)

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val delayMillis = 500L // 0.5 seconds

        Handler().postDelayed({
            binding.tabLayoutTaskReward.getTabAt(0)?.select()
        }, delayMillis)
    }
```